# ServletOutputStream, получение данных

Tags: java, spring-boot

Моя проблема состоит в следующем:

1. есть сторонний сервис A, к коду которого доступа нет и переписывать его никто не будет. У сервиса есть функция, позволяющая получить фото пользователя, с синтаксисом getPhoto(Long userID, HttpServletResponse response). Соответственно, данные находятся в response.getOutputStream().
2. есть мой сервис B, который согласно расписанию запускает интеграцию с сервисом A. В рамках интеграции необходимо обновить фото, т. е. забрать новое с сервиса A и заменить существующее в хранилище (папка на диске)

Получить фото иным способом, кроме как через указанную функцию - нет. В связи с этим встает вопрос: каким образом из response.getOutputStream(), который возвращает объект ServletOutputStream, получить данные? Или, возможно, есть способ записать их напрямую в файл?

Сервис B использует Spring-Boot.

Опытным путем было установлено, что к ByteArrayOutputStream привести ServletOutputStream нельзя.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387483/how-to-read-servletoutputstream

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=read+ServletOutputStream&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA810UA810&oq=read+ServletOutputStream&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1536j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Tsyklop не помогло